# Добавить поле для атрибута при его создании WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно добавить поле на страницу "wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes" (скрин ниже), которое, естественно, будет сохраняться в бд

В идеале, чтобы был select из имеющихся категорий товара. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Есть плагин ACF (Advanced Custom Field).
В нём легко для таксономий и любых типов постов делаются дополнительные "поля".
Вопрос лишь в том, что потом надо будет получить значение в шаблоне, во ФронтЭнде через код или Хуки и вывести что надо и где надо.
А так, вы добавите поле, выберете условие (для каких сущностей оно) для какого типа таксономии, категории и в админке оно появится.

Comment: Там нет нужной сущности для условия. И как ее добавить - тоже без понятия(

Comment: Там есть всё. Я все свои задачи легко решаю. Какой тип записей тебя интересует? product_attributes - это атрибуты товара. В условиях отображения произвольного поля выбирай ФОРМЫ -> Таксономия и в следующем поле выбирай нужную. Можно сделать условие, вывода поля в нескольких, нажимая добавить с условием ИЛИ.

Comment: Абсолютно верно, так и у меня работает, но данные способ добавляет поле на страницу самого атрибута. Например на страницу "Красный", "Зеленый" и тд. А мне нужно на страницу создания атрибута, на пример на стр "Цвет"

Comment: Страница "цвет" и др. (создание атрибута) не является целевым объектом, это группа, у которой есть кнопка создать, которая через аякс,  создаёт целевой объект, а посему на неё прикрепить без костылей или кода не получится. Если бы задача была описана более развёрнуто, я бы это не писал, а написал другое. Пишите логику, что должно получиться и для чего.  Получается что Вы хотите проверять свойство атрибута pa_color (пример) и в зависимости от того, что есть у родителя, отображать свойство или нет?

Comment: Описал максимально подробно, прикрепил ссылку и скрин страницы. Мне просто нужно доп поле (можно просто текстовое) при создании атрибута, которое будет сохраняться в админке, пробовал это (https://coderoad.ru/61414581/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-woocommerce), но оно не сохраняется после заполнения

Comment: Надо смотреть и искать, что за хук отвечает за update значения при записи. Я посмотрю, когда будет минутка. Завтра отвечу. Вешать туда update твоего мета поля.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128419/discussion-between-sergio-and-ck1e).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Это выбираем тип таксономии]

[image: Это выбираем атрибут]

На картинке видны атрибуты Цвет, размер и другие, свойственные товарам. Но там есть и другие, не относящиеся к товарам. В связи с чем надо добавлять и перечислять те, в которых необходимо, что бы появились доп. поля.